# Unexpected CV joint disassembly - want to verify fix

Tags: toyota, sienna, cv-joint

I was replacing the struts on my 2009 Toyota Sienna FWD when the passenger side  CV joint separated (the tripod slid out of the housing). The large clamp broke and about 4-6 ounces of grease fell to the floor. I was able to get everything reassembled then I added approximately the same amount of grease back into the boot and put a worm-style hose clamp on the boot.  I dont know much about CV joints so I dont know if I should be worried about anything. So far its driven about 100 miles since then without any issue. I used a valvoline synthetic grease designed for wheel bearings and CV joints.

Do I have any reason to be concerned?  I have a family road trip coming up in 3 weeks and I am a little nervous. Thanks.

Comment: Inner or Outer CV joint???

Comment: Inner...closest to transmission

Comment: You are fine, I have had this happen more than once.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the bearings etc were kept clean and everything was in the same position from where it came, you should be fine..

The only thing that may occur if the bearings or cup have rotated before refitting is perhaps premature wear of the joint, as the bearings will now be wearing in a different manner to their previous wear pattern. I wouldn't worry too much though unless the joint was excessively worn or knocking etc to begin with.